# How to turn these 3 scripts into 1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I have a script that does similar things for different id's and i'm pretty much certain this can be done in 1 script rather than 3, any suggestions are welcome.

```
$("#size-btn-one").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scroll-one").offset().top -100}, 2000);
    });
});

$("#size-btn-two").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scroll-two").offset().top -100}, 2000);
    });
});

$("#size-btn-three").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scroll-three").top -100}, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combine the selector, you can make an `and` select by comma separation, like you did with `html, body` too. And you can extract the name from the element `id` by different ways, e.g with a simple replace.

```
$("#size-btn-one, #size-btn-two, #size-btn-three").click(function() {
    // getting only the last part of the elements id
    var id = $(this).attr("id").replace("size-btn-", "");

    $("html, body").animate({
        // append the 'id' to the selector class
        scrollTop: $(".scroll-" + id).offset().top -100}, 2000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$("#size-btn-one, #size-btn-two, #size-btn-three").click(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var number = id.substring(id.lastIndexOf("-"));

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".scroll-"+ number).offset().top -100}, 2000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi if you notice the id #size-btn-one, #size-btn-two or #size-btn-three needs to animate to .scroll-one, .scroll-two or .scroll-three

Comment: Yes I am getting the number from the id and using it in the animate function  `scrollTop: $(".scroll-"+ number).offset().top -100}, 2000);`

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, I'd pair up the `btn` and the `scroll-` using `data-` attributes and not use `id=` for this.

```
<a href='#' data-link='1'>one</a>
<a href='#' data-link='2'>one</a>
<a href='#' data-link='xyz'>one</a>

<div data-link='1'>content 1</div>
<div data-link='2'>content 2</div>
<div data-link='xyz'>content 3</div>
```

This also means you can use semantic definitions, rather than just numbers (though you could with IDs as well ofc).

Then:

```
$("a[data-link]").click(function() {
    var link = $(this).data("link");
    var div = $("div[data-link=" + link + "]");

    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: div.offset().top - 100}, 2000);
    });
});
```

Normally, you'd also add a class, but left off to show the concept of pairing via data attributes.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#size-btn-one, #size-btn-two, #size-btn-three").on("click",function(){
  var idLastPart = $(this).attr('id');
  idLastPart = idLastPart.match(/one|two|three/)[0];
  $('.scroll-'+idLastPart).animate({
          //your animation
  },300);
});
```

Comment: This approach is a bit bad to maintain. When adding new elements you always have to edit the regex too. Double work for a thing that can be easily done by other ways imo.

Comment: And you got an error there too, `.scroll-` is an class, not an id.

Comment: Please edit with more information. Code-only and "try this" answers are discouraged, because they contain no searchable content, and don't explain why someone should "try this".

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!

Comment: thanx for suggestions, I'll try my best in the future!